# Google sky map API for android and iPhone

Tags: iphone, android

I want to develop an application in iPhone and Android both which can display the details about the position and location of planets in the universe. Surfing google I have come across Google Sky Map. But I am not finding any resource or API to do this. So please suggest what can be done to do this. Is this thing possible? Also I have seen some apps on itunes and Android that already possess this kind of functionality but I am not sure about how they must have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for sky map. The apps on the stores have their own private databases of interstellar data. You might be able to find such a database somewhere online, but I doubt it will be free. One option you have is making a script to crawl Wikipedia and retrieve the star statistics from that.